# I want to receive data from PLC port 502 with TCP socket in PHP, but I cannot receive data

Tags: php, sockets, plc

I want to receive data from PLC TCP/Ip port 502 with php socket programming.
I confirm that the data is coming from the plc with the help of simple programs.

I can't get data with PHP socket tcp programming. Can you help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Flyqk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXDzD.png)

```
<?php
$address = "10.22.100.210";
$port = 502;
// No Timeout 

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
$result = socket_bind($socket, $address, $port) or die("Could not connecttt toserver\n");

//$resultt = socket_connect($socket, $address, $port) or die("Noo nOOO\n");

echo "<pre>";
echo "problemm: ".$result;
echo "<pre>";

//$resultt = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("sokett dinlenemezzz");
//$client=socket_accept($socket);
//$result1 = socket_read($client, 1024) or die("Ceccevapp yokkk\n");

socket_recvfrom($socket, $buffer,12,0,$address,$port) or die("olmadııı");
//echo "gelen veriii : " . $resultt;
echo "serverdan gelennn cvpp  :" . bin2hex($buffer);
//echo "gelen bilgi : ".$result1;

socket_close($socket);
```

I can read data from plc with different programs. But I cannot read it with php tcp socket.
I observed that there was communication in the wireshark record.

Comment: Are you supposed to send something before receiving? The PLc might be waiting for you to send first.

Comment: What does `socket_last_error()` give you?

Comment: Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [10049]:

Comment: And `10.22.100.210` is the IP address of this machine running PHP?

Comment: Yes, the IP address of the computer where php runs.